# I want to click a Tkinter button and then export the searched item to excel file, how can I do that?

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
def print_area(self, txt):
        try:
            con = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='', db='philanthropy')
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("select * from istavrity where familycode LIKE '%"+self.var_search.get()+"%'")
            row=cur.fetchall()
            for i in row:
                fName = i[1]
           
            if len(row)>0:
                row_list = []
                columns = ('S.N.', 'Family Code', 'Family Name', 'Ritwik', 'Swastyayani', 'Family Name', 'Ritwik', 'Swastyayani', 'FamilyCode', 'Family Name', 'Ritwik', 'Swastyayani', 'FamilyCode', 'Family Name', 'Ritwik', 'Swastyayani', 'ravv')
                self.employee_tree.delete(*self.employee_tree.get_children())
                for i in row:
                    self.employee_tree.insert('',END,values=i)
                    row_list.append(i)
                treeview_df = pd.DataFrame(row_list, columns = columns)
                print(treeview_df)
                treeview_df.to_excel(f"excel_backup/{fName}.xlsx")
            else:
                self.employee_tree.delete(*self.employee_tree.get_children())
        except Exception as ex:
            messagebox.showerror("Error",f"Error due to {str(ex)}")
```

The search area code is

```py
btn_search = Button(root, text="Search", font=("times new roman", 12), bg="white",fg="black").place(x=800,y=5, height=20)
        self.txt_search = Entry(root,textvariable=self.var_search, font=("goudy old style",15,'bold'), bg="white",fg="blue")
        self.txt_search.place(x=870,y=5,height=20,width=250)
        self.txt_search.bind("<Key>", self.search)
```

And the button code is:

```py
self.btn_print = Button(root,text="Print", font=("times new roman", 15), bg="red", fg="white")
        self.btn_print.pack()
```

The search function is almost similar to print_area function:

```
def search(self,ev):
        
        try:
            con = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='', db='philanthropy')
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("select * from istavrity where familycode LIKE '%"+self.var_search.get()+"%'")
            row=cur.fetchall()
           
            if len(row)>0:
                self.employee_tree.delete(*self.employee_tree.get_children())
                for i in row:
                    self.employee_tree.insert('',END,values=i)
            else:
                self.employee_tree.delete(*self.employee_tree.get_children())
        except Exception as ex:
            messagebox.showerror("Error",f"Error due to {str(ex)}")
```

The problem is, just by searching the fcode, it gets exported without clicking button.

Comment: Just started the tKinter, totally noob, I'm trying to learn. Please Help.

Comment: No code on `search()`.  It is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: @acw1668 I have edited the question and added the code of search function. Please Review.

search function is almost like print_area.

Actually I want to fetch data and export to xlsx and print those data directly.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your posted code has never called `print_area()` so I wonder why you have the issue.

Comment: @acw1668 Yes, exactly, what I need is after calling print_area() I need excel file, without calling or pressing button I'm getting the excel file as soon as I attempt to search.